# Is there a way to "clear" a CSS property as if never existed?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am using a CDN css file which sets a "top" property for an item which was recently added as a new release. This 'top' property completely throws off the height of a list item in my code. I am certain this is the culprit by use of Firebug.

Normally, I am able to override previously directed CSS properties (such as height, color, etc) but is there a way to essentially say "forget that I told you to set `top: 24px`, I want you to ignore that".

In essence:

```
.some-class > a:after {
 ....
   top: 24px;
}
```

(in another file)

```
.some-class > a:after {
   top: gothehellaway
}
```

Note: I have tried setting to 0, auto, and inherit without successful results.

### Update 1:

I have tried using the recommended `inherit` but it does not work in any tested browser. I have also used `top: auto !important` and `top: inherit !important` without luck.

### Update 2:

Just noticed in the CDN CSS file, there are actually two calls for the exact same property (although no idea why Zurb did it this way. Damn you Foundation 4):

```
.top-bar-section .has-dropdown > a:after {
    ...
    top: 50%;
}

.top-bar-section .has-dropdown > a:after {
    ...
    top: 22.5px;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use the !important keyword?

Comment: !important    Nothing is more important than this while overriding CSS!!!!

Comment: @MVP - I did not. !important on which value?

Comment: @JM4 On the value you want to keep. !important will always have the highest priority and cannot be overwritten, not even by inline styles.

Comment: @MVP - updating but no luck

Comment: Did you remember to include the semicolon `;`? If you were setting multiple properties within `.some-class > a:after`, it would be a syntax error if you didn’t separate them with `;`. So the whole second line should be `top: inherit !important;`.

Comment: If that’s not the problem, perhaps the property causing the problem is not `top`, but `margin-top` or `padding-top`. Or there is a `top` on `.some-class > a` as well that you need to reset.

Comment: @Rory - not a semi colon issue. Definitely seems to be the top property. If I "delete" it while not using the CDN all works as it *should*.

Comment: Can we have a link?  This might be a `specificity` issue.

Comment: Did you try using a higher-precedence call for that class? For instance if it's always within a div with ID="poppa", then use `#poppa .top-bar-section .has-dropdown > a:after { top: auto; }`.  Tack on an `!important` too if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`initial` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) represents the browser’s default value for a property.

```css
.some-class > a:after {
   top: initial;
}
```

`initial` has long been supported in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari, but is not supported in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Why two downvotes? Is there anything wrong with this answer? It seems at least as good as [David’s](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18090083/578288), which was posted after mine.

Comment: Note: this does not work on my tests.

However, no idea why people downvoted you here and not David if that was the reason. I did not downvote, FWIW though I do show it was posted after.

Comment: Neither did I downvote but as a comment, `top: initial` doesn't work in IE.

Comment: @JM4 It works for me in both Chrome and Firefox when I set `color: initial` on an element on this very page. And the [compatibility table on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial#Browser_compatibility) says it should work in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane - I have tested in all browsers without any luck but perhaps it is due to my second update. Regardless, a solution without taking into account IE isn't one which will help me unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Use `initial` to set it

for example

`.some-class > a:after { top:initial; }`

HTH